# How to prevent \raggedright from removing left-indent of \parshape?

Tags: indentation, hyphenation, ragged2e, parshape, justification

Output with `\raggedright` looks good when greater indentation is specified for `\parshape`, but `\raggedright` eats up smaller indentation.

If a word doesn't fit on a line, is there a way to prevent hyphenation and move the entire word to the next line without touching paragraph indentation (what I thought `\raggedright` would do) specified with `\parshape`?

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \parbox{40mm}
    { \parshape 3 0pt 113.81102pt 14.44pt 99.37102pt 17.77pt 96.04102pt
      \raggedright % comment this line to see the difference
      % \tolerance 0 % uncomment this line when \raggedright is commented
      \textbullet\ This is sentence 1.\\This is sentence 2.
      This is sentence 3.
    }
\end{document}
```

No `\raggedright` (indentation is preserved but inter-word spacing is excessive):

[image]

With `\raggedright` (no excessive inter-word spacing but indentation is ruined):

[image]

No `\raggedright` but with `\tolerance 0` (too narrow inter-word spacing this time, and overflowed letter *s*; I need the word *This* to be moved to the next line automatically):

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\raggedright` redefines `\\`: it internally inserts a `\par` and so actually ends your \parshape. You can use \newline instead of `\\`:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\begin{document}
 \parbox{40mm}
    { \parshape 3 0pt 113.81102pt 14.44pt 99.37102pt 17.77pt 96.04102pt
      \raggedright 
      \textbullet\ This is sentence 1 \newline This is sentence 2
      This is sentence 3
    }

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or set `\rightskip`:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\begin{document}
 \parbox{40mm}
    { \parshape 3 0pt 113.81102pt 14.44pt 99.37102pt 17.77pt 96.04102pt
      \rightskip 0pt plus 1fil
      \textbullet\ This is sentence 1 \\ This is sentence 2
      This is sentence 3
    }

\end{document}
```